# How to redirect NodeJs logs from console to file

Tags: node.js, winston

I'm very new in NodeJs. Afair NodeJs does not write log to file directly so I have to use external logging library. Let's say Winston.

I would like to have all modules write logs to files created by Winston, also I would like to have all console.log/console.info to be written to Winston too.

```
const logger = createLogger({
    format: combine(
        appendTimestamp({ tz: 'Europe/London' }),
        myFormat
    ),
    transports: [
        new transports.Console(),
        new winston.transports.File({
            filename: 'error.log',
            dirname: '/logs/',
            level: 'error',
            datePattern: 'yyyy-MM-dd.'
        }),
        new winston.transports.File({
            filename: 'application.log',
            dirname: '/logs/',
            datePattern: 'yyyy-MM-dd.'
        })
    ]
});
```

If I use `logger.info` - it works fine. However I still can see that some modules are using stout/stderr.

In Java this problem solved as following - every third party library use logging adapter. Nothing is written in stdout, stderr. By including logging library and logging configuration in classpath, all application logs generated by application itself and its dependencies goes to one place.

I know, I can redirect logs as following node `node index.js > mylog.js` but I want my logs to be rotated.

What is the good practice for log writing in app -  using custom logger or using console.log/console.info?

How other 3-rd party modules/libraries are writing log messages? Are they using console.log or it's good to have some kind of logging adapter like in Java.

Maybe I can use something like this, but I'm not sure if it's proper way

```
console.log = function() {
   logger.info.apply(null, arguments);
}

console.error = function() {
   logger.error.apply(null, arguments);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`console` is a global, used by many libraries to output logs to stdout. There is no "proper" way to intercept all of these calls to `console.log` without modifying the global as you have an example of in your question.

For what it's worth, logs can be rotated with tools like [`logrotate`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate). Redirecting `stdout` is a pretty good idea for your process if you want to capture *all* output. Some 3rd-party libraries will provide a way for you to inject your own logger, but this is not the case most of the time (to my knowledge).